# filtrando contenido en selects anidados

Tags: javascript, html

¡Hola!

¿Como puedo filtrar el contenido de un municipio dependiendo la provincia que elija?

Sucede que Tengo 3 selects. uno para la provincia, uno para el municipio y uno para el sector.

Lo que sucede aquí es que al elegir una provincia se filtran todos los municipios de golpe. y lo que quiero es que se filtren dependiendo la provincia que elija.

Lo que estoy haciendo es crear un data attribute por provincia y luego en el evento change del select de las provincias cargo la función para los municipios y le paso por parámetro el attribute para que se filtre.

aquí el código:

Aclaro que  la de los sectores aún no la programo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Selects anidados con localidades de República Dominicana</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Selects anidados con localidades de República Dominicana</h1>
    <label for="id_provincia">Provincia</label>
    <select name="provincia" id="id_provincia">
        <option value="">Selecciona una provincia</option>
    </select>
    <p></p>

    <br>
    <label for="id_municipio">Municipio</label>
    <select name="municipio" id="id_municipio">
        <option value="">Selecciona un municipio</option>
    </select>
    <p></p>

    <br>
    <label for="id_sector">Sector</label>
    <select name="sector" id="id_sector">
        <option value="">Selecciona un sector</option>
    </select>
    <p></p>

    <script src="app/selects_anidados.js"></script>

</body>
</html>


const d = document,
    provincias = d.getElementById("id_provincia"),
    municipios = d.getElementById("id_municipio"),
    sectores = d.getElementById("id_sector");


const cargaProvincias = () => {
    fetch("https://api.digital.gob.do/v1/territories/provinces")

        .then((respuesta) => {
            //console.info(respuesta);
            return (respuesta.ok) ? respuesta.json() : Promise.reject(respuesta);
        })

        .then((respJson) => {
            //console.info(respJson);

            respJson.data.forEach((elemento) => {
                let opciones = d.createElement("option");
                opciones.value = elemento.name;
                opciones.text = elemento.name;
                opciones.setAttribute("data-provincecode", elemento.provinceCode);
                provincias.add(opciones);
            });

        })

        .catch((err) => {
            let mensajeError = err.statusText || "Ocurrió un error";
            provincias.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = `Error ${err.status} ${mensajeError}`;
            console.error(err);
        });
}

const cargaMunicipio = (provincia) => {
    fetch(`https://api.digital.gob.do/v1/territories/municipalities?provincecode=${provincia}`)

        .then((respuesta) => {
            console.info(respuesta);
            return (respuesta.ok) ? respuesta.json() : Promise.reject(respuesta);
        })

        .then((respJson) => {
            console.info(respJson);

            respJson.data.forEach((elemento) => {
                let opciones = d.createElement("option");
                opciones.value = elemento.name;
                opciones.text = elemento.name;
                municipios.add(opciones);
            });

        })

        .catch((err) => {
            let mensajeError = err.statusText || "Ocurrió un error";
            municipios.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = `Error ${err.status} ${mensajeError}`;
            console.error(err);
        });

}

const cargaSector = (municipio) => {

}

d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", cargaProvincias);

provincias.addEventListener("change", (ev) => {
    const selectedOption = ev.target.options[ev.target.selectedIndex];
    const provincecode = selectedOption.getAttribute("data-provincecode");
    cargaMunicipio(provincecode);
    console.info(provincecode);
});

sectores.addEventListener("change", (ev) => {
    cargaSector(ev.target.value);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Al parecer cuando intentas filtrar las opciones el parametro del api no es correcta, [https://api.digital.gob.do/v1/territories/municipalities?**regionCode**=${provincia}](https://api.digital.gob.do/v1/territories/municipalities?**regionCode**=$%7Bprovincia%7D)
Ademas de agregar solo una funcion que limpie las opciones, espero resuelva tu problema.

```js
const d = document,
    provincias = d.getElementById("id_provincia"),
    municipios = d.getElementById("id_municipio"),
    sectores = d.getElementById("id_sector");


const cargaProvincias = () => {
    fetch("https://api.digital.gob.do/v1/territories/provinces")

        .then((respuesta) => {
            //console.info(respuesta);
            return (respuesta.ok) ? respuesta.json() : Promise.reject(respuesta);
        })

        .then((respJson) => {
            //console.info(respJson);

            respJson.data.forEach((elemento) => {
                let opciones = d.createElement("option");
                opciones.value = elemento.name;
                opciones.text = elemento.name;
                opciones.setAttribute("data-provincecode", elemento.regionCode);
                provincias.add(opciones);
            });

        })

        .catch((err) => {
            let mensajeError = err.statusText || "Ocurrió un error";
            provincias.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = `Error ${err.status} ${mensajeError}`;
            console.error(err);
        });
}

const cargaMunicipio = (provincia) => {
    fetch(`https://api.digital.gob.do/v1/territories/municipalities?regionCode=${provincia}`)

        .then((respuesta) => {
            //console.info(respuesta);
            return (respuesta.ok) ? respuesta.json() : Promise.reject(respuesta);
        })

        .then((respJson) => {
            //console.info(respJson);

            respJson.data.forEach((elemento) => {
                let opciones = d.createElement("option");
                opciones.value = elemento.name;
                opciones.text = elemento.name;
                municipios.add(opciones);
            });

        })

        .catch((err) => {
            let mensajeError = err.statusText || "Ocurrió un error";
            municipios.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = `Error ${err.status} ${mensajeError}`;
            console.error(err);
        });

}

const cargaSector = (municipio) => {

}

d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", cargaProvincias);

provincias.addEventListener("change", (ev) => {
    const selectedOption = ev.target.options[ev.target.selectedIndex];
    const provincecode = selectedOption.getAttribute("data-provincecode");
    limpiar(municipios); // Limpiar municipios
    limpiar(sectores);   // Limpiar sectores

    cargaMunicipio(provincecode);
    console.info(provincecode);
    //console.info(provincecode);
});

sectores.addEventListener("change", (ev) => {
    cargaSector(ev.target.value);
});

const limpiar = (select) => {
    while (select.options.length > 1) {
        select.remove(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Selects anidados con localidades de República Dominicana</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Selects anidados con localidades de República Dominicana</h1>
    <label for="id_provincia">Provincia</label>
    <select name="provincia" id="id_provincia">
        <option value="">Selecciona una provincia</option>
    </select>
    <p></p>

    <br>
    <label for="id_municipio">Municipio</label>
    <select name="municipio" id="id_municipio">
        <option value="">Selecciona un municipio</option>
    </select>
    <p></p>

    <br>
    <label for="id_sector">Sector</label>
    <select name="sector" id="id_sector">
        <option value="">Selecciona un sector</option>
    </select>
    <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola colega. si bien funciona, hay un problema. cuando filtras por regiones y seleccionas una provincia que tiene un número de región en común con otra provincia, se despliegan todos los municipios de las provincias con ese número de región. Lo que yo busco es que se me filtren solo los municipios de esa provincia que seleccioné, y no toda la región. Pero si hace el limpiado del select.